# Easy admin bundle: how to access parameter array of MenuItem::linktoRoute fourth parameter

Tags: php, symfony, easyadmin

in my DashboarController I add a link to one of my routes in the `configureMenuItems()` function like this: `yield MenuItem::linktoRoute('Title', 'icon', 'my_index', ['key' => 'value']);`.
In my Controller I trie to access the parameter as usual like this:

```
/**
 * @Route("/my", name="my_")
 */
class OneController extends AbstractController
{
     /**
     * @Route("/{key}", name="index")
     */
    public function index(string $key): Response
    {
        return $this->render('my_index/index.html.twig', [
            'controller_name' => 'OneController',
            'key' => 'someKey'
        ]);
    }
}
```

But I get the error `No route found for GET /my`. Without using the parameter `{key}` I can call the page.

Can somebody help me how to access the parameter array of `linktoRoute()` ?

Thanks in advance!

UPDATE:

The solution is: `bin/console cache:clear` followed by `bin/console cache:warmup` then you can find the parameters as GET-Parameters...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is: bin/console cache:clear followed by bin/console cache:warmup then you can find the parameters as GET-Parameters...